Any reason I can't connect two sewage ejector tanks with a hose?
I know this idea is probably wildly unprofessional, but I've been dealing with sewage overflowing when either one of my two below-grade sewage ejector pumps dies, OR one of the two float switches stops working (which has happened 3 times in the last 4 years).
It seems to me that since someone went to the trouble to set up two separate pumps side-by-side to handle the two downstairs bathrooms, they could at least be made redundant in some way.
My mockup for your consideration (or mockery):

My theory is that if the tank is overflowing (and of course no one ever seems to hear the alarm until after they're done their shower) and the water is backed up the pipe so far that it's created enough pressure to spray water through every crack and seal in the top of the tank, then it would happily flow through a hose tucked into the top of each tank (where the cables go in) and pass over to the other working tank before doing too much collateral damage.
Someone please tell me how genius this idea is?

Not a solution (as I don't know the relevant plumbing code) but a comical possibility: hook up a solenoid to the alarm circuits that turns off the water main. People will notice the alarm much quicker if the water stops working the moment of the alarms is going off.
